# I migrated WPMU site: Unable to create directory uploads/... Desperate for help!

Tags: uploads, permissions

Desperate for help!

I MANUALLY transferred a WPMU site to a new server, root folder, and now have a constant “Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will not be functional.” which in fact turns out to be true. I’m unable to export/import my WooCommerce CSV files.

I’ve set attributes to /wp-content/uploads to 777, to no avail. I’ve searched google and WP forums, to no avail – I desperately need some direction on how to fix this problem. If anyone could please step in and offer me some help I’d be so very grateful.

Comment: 755 should be plenty, for folders.  Did you recurse the chmod through all the subfolders within the /uploads/ directory?

Comment: Have you tried your host provider about this issue? Most of the times they can resolve these type of problems quickly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to both of you who answered. The problem turned out to be that there are more than one rows in wp_options which refer to the uploads folder: upload_path, upload_url_path and fileupload_url - I had only found one of these when I searched "upload_url" and missed the first one, which was of course pointing to the old server.

By searching "upload path" i found all three, made the correction and solved the problem.